# What does the error "pre.period must span at least 3 time points" in the CausalImpact R package mean?

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, causality, causalimpact

I've been encountering the error "pre.period must span at least 3 time points" when using the package. Can someone help me understand why the package requires me to have at least 3 time points and what modifications I could do for the package to run my data?

Here's my pre.period and post.period inputs:

```
> pre.period
 "2013-03-05" "2014-08-06"

> post.period
 "2014-08-07" "2014-08-21"
```

Looking through the GitHub repo of the package here's the snippet of code:

```
  assert(pre.period[2] - pre.period[1] + 1 >= 3,
         "pre.period must span at least 3 time points")
  assert_that(post.period[2] >= post.period[1])
  assert_that(post.period[1] > pre.period[2])
  return(list(pre.period = pre.period, post.period = post.period))
```

You can view more of the code here:
https://github.com/google/CausalImpact/blob/master/R/impact_analysis.R

Thanks

Comment: Please, check your date column has 'date' or 'time' as name. Otherwise the method raises an error. They should mention that in the documentation :-)
Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

The CasualImpact package is essentially a time series package. It uses Bayesian structure time series models, so the pre period can be thought of as a training period, used to determine the relationship between the response variable and the covariates.

I don't know what your data looks like but it seems to me that you have a time series with 4 observations. That means that you are trying to train your model with only 2 observations. The package requires 3 observations but you should probably have much more than that, because you cannot do reliable inference with 2 data points. If you have data on different individuals for those 4 days then you may be able to estimate a diff-and-diff model, which will suits better your data.